# Can't Post facebook URL using facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, jsonp, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a webapplication that I use to reshare existing post as follow
1)get the post details  using https://graph.facebook.com/UserID_postID?access_token=AAA (works fine)
2)fill the a data of the new post from the old one and try to resend it but there is some strange behviour 
if I use 
oldpost.link = newpost.link   it doesnt nothing appear on the wall but if I used
oldpost.link="\""newpost.link+"\"" works and the post appear on facebook wall but the link appears corputted as invalid.invalid/

function getPost(userID, postID, token) {
    jQuery.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "_" + postID + "?access_token=" + token, function (post) {
     here is the code any idea please

```
    var newPost = {};
    newPost.message = "hi";
      if (post.link != "" && post.link != null && post.link != "undefined") {
            newPost.link = "\"" + post.link + "\"";
        }
        if (post.name != "" && post.name != null && post.name != "undefined") {
            newPost.name = "\"" + post.name + "\"";
        }
        if (post.picture != "" && post.picture != null && post.picture != "undefined") {
            newPost.picture = "\"" + post.picture + "\"";
        }
        if (post.description != "" && post.description != null && post.description != "undefined") {
            newPost.description = "\"" + post.description + "\"";
        }



        doPost(newPost);
    });
}

function doPost(newPost) {

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post',
              newPost, function (response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert(' Denied Access');
                    } else {
                        alert('Success');
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: Use a JS debugger (f.e. the one build-in in Firebug), and see what’s _actually_ going on in your code.